Should I be able to see light from a IR Led with my own eyes?
I know that infrared light should not be visible to the human eye.
I connected a diode and phototransistor from the encoder of an old printer and I can see a red dot. My worries are that the device is burnt and that I am just watching it glow (although it would probably smell like somethings is burning.) One of my theories is that this kind of device comes with a filter so I can see the red dots, just in security cameras. I am really not sure if the LED (and the phototransistor) are actually working.


In general you can see bright sources up to and beyond 800 nm in the NIR, and I have aligned 850nm lasers with no difficulty seeing their beam. However, what makes you sure that you have an IR LED? Red LEDs exist too.

Can you measure the LED forward voltage? Below 1.5 V it normally is IR, above it is just a red LED.

Can confirm, they are generally visible to the eye -- if extremely dimly (and not without risk, as others have mentioned!), and preferably in dark conditions. The apparent intensity may also vary from person to person.

Hello. The forward voltage is around 1.9 V so I still have my doubts. I think it's an IR diode because phototransistors are more sensitive to such light (according to the internet), that's why I don't think it's a red LED, but I might be wrong.

As someone who has overdriven many an LED, the failure mode is not a dull red glow. You would likely see a brief flicker, sometimes accompanied by a small crackle.
IR emitters have their peak at 850 nm or whatever but their output spectrum is broad enough to include the far red end of color vision. Your camera's sensor is also much more sensitive to IR than the human eye. There are filters to reduce the response, but their cutoff isn't perfectly sharp.

[+1] There's a plot of that at the end of this long answer

Some IR emitters peak at 850nm (weakly visible). 940nm is very common and you'll never see that by eye.  You might on a camera depending on how good its IR blocking filter is. 940nm is used in remote controls.  850nm is used in night illumination for security cameras and is quite easy to see depending on the ambient light

Note that it's quite common that IR light on security cameras glows quite visibly.


Should I be able to see light from a IR Led with my own eyes?

The perceived intensity of light falls off rapidly at wavelengths above 700 nm. Typically, signals at 810 nm not noticeable. However, if the signal is sufficiently strong, and the ambient lighting is sufficiently "dark" for signals below 810 nm, then a 810 nm signal will be visible, and appear red, even though 810 nm is generally regarded is within the infra-red range. The article The Sensitivity of the Human Eye to Infra-Red Radiation by Griffin, Hubbard, and Wald, appearing in the Journal of the Optical Society of America gives more information.
So, it is possible for humans to see (some wavelengths) of infrared light. Whether you saw infrared light under the conditions you describe is another question. If the LED was not the only source of light in the room, it is likely that you did not see IR light. Similarly, if the LED was of low power, drawing, say 20 mA, which is not atypical, that would reduce the probability that you saw IR radiation, but it still might be possible.

Yes, LED was not the only light source, I took the picture during the day. And it was running at around 5v 500 ohm resistance. Makes me think if the IR receiver will even function with that kind of light.

@Gabo the receiver will probably have something to filter out visible ambient light (though sometimes this is implemented just by putting it down a hole, so it can only see a narrow range of angles).  You can't trust your visiual perception of brightness in the (very) near IR - I used to work with IR lasers that looked like red lasers about 1000× weaker.  But you can't trust your camera either because it will have an IR  reducing filter of unknown specifications.

The 50% IR BW is very narrow, and our eyes should not stare at a 100 mA IR LED to prevent damage up close to avoid damage.  The spectral shape looks more linear at the log-lin power curve.
The same is true for Blue White spotlight LEDs with UV so they are banned in Art galleries. The level is OK for humans to see the reflected light but not for sensitive artwork over decades of aging.
Here is my estimate of the IR intensity at deep red on the left.  There may also be a left shift of wavelength with more thermal energy on the LED.

We use a dominant (D) Lambda for CIE eye correct colour and a peak (P) Lambda for spectrometer readings. Deep red is 660 nmP
There may be other energy factors that make the deep red look faded or with white. This is just a SWAG using the eye's logarithmic range for a typical IR emitter.

I think I see what you're going for here, but it's a bit unclear: 1. no one asked about bandwidth (or necessarily hinted that it's an understood concept!), this seems to come out of the blue (ha); 2. you plot emission vs. wavelength, but what applicability does this have? --> 3. there should be a comparable plot showing visual response vs. wavelength, so that on multiplying both curves and integrating, an apparent visible gain factor is obtained. This, and explaining how LEDs emit (bandwidth is a spread of wavelength, LEDs are normally somewhat broad, etc.), will make this an excellent answer.

Perfect approach and a good answer. The tail of IR emission overlaps with the tail of human vision, that simple. Every 850nm LED will show a glowing red dot.

Our eyes can see over 60 dB range on black dot TV screens and the sun is 100 dB above 1 Lux.
